# Slick Scala Mockito dao mocking

Tags: scala, testing, mockito, slick

I have a base trait for dao:

```
trait BaseDao[T, A] {
  ...
  def deleteByFilter[C: CanBeQueryCondition](f: T => C): Future[Int]
}
```

and I would love to be able to mock such a method.
Maybe someting like this:

```
val someMock = mock[BaseDao[EntityTable, Entity]]
someMock.deleteByFilter(anyFunction1[Posts, Rep[Boolean]].apply) returns Future(1)
// or
someMock.deleteByFilter(anyFunction1[Posts, Rep[Boolean]]) returns Future(1)
```

but no metter what I try I always get:

```
[info]   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers!
[info] 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
[info] -> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.ArgThat$class.anArgThat(ArgThat.scala:11)
```

How can I successfully stub this method?

Comment: I found some workaround:

`import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

def f(x: EntityTable): Rep[Boolean] = x.id ===1L && x.isActive === true`